# Convolution, g(t)=sin(t)

Tags: convolution

I have two functions:

$f(t)=(t+\pi)\theta(t+\pi)-2t\theta(t)+(t+\pi)\theta(t-\pi)$, (looks like $-|x|+1, -\pi < x < \pi$ )

and

$g(t) = \sin{(t)}$

Could someone please point me in the right direction of how to solve the convolution of $f(t)*g(t)$ ?

Thanks

Comment: @user31r2264 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

$$f*g=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(t-t')f(t')dt'=\int_{-\pi}^0 \sin(t-t')(t'+\pi)dt'+\int_0^{\pi} \sin(t-t')(\pi-t')dt'$$

And I'll presume that you can finish the integrals.

Comment: Thanks! That was my intention, got confused from the different teachers different answers..

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.